# Can I dimiss or kill my steward but keep my bard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I live in Winstad Manor. I just live with my wife currently. In an earlier save I hired Valdimir as a steward and Sonir as a bard. I liked Sonir [as long as she doesn't sing "The Dragonborn Comes", it's not a good number for her] and want to keep her, but, when I hired Valdimir as a steward beforehand he started wandering in and out of the house all the time, eating bread and sitting in the private bedroom, which is clearly not on.

How do I get rid of him and keep Sonir? I take it that the only thing to do, without mods, is to kill him. If I do so, will Sonir stay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bard is not tied to your Steward. You can replace your Steward with whatever method you find suitable and it does not affect the Bard.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I ended up killing Valdimir as a werewolf. I felt very guilty for doing so but am more or less over it now. I hired Illia instead, who I really like. She's very humble and sweet, and I don't mind her wandering around the house. She's also an expert with frost magic, so she is perfectly capable of holding her own when the place gets attacked. Ironically, after all that, I haven't hired Sonir, only because her music sometimes conflicts with the in-game music in the house.